# How Hailo and Uber gets driver's location in background in iOS?

Tags: ios, background, location

Can someone help me on this as iOS doesn't allow to run anything in background for long and it kills the app if it uses a lot of memory. So how do we get user's location in background continuously without apple killing your app.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to enable the Location Updates Background Mode from your project settings, and then you must call the method `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` from your `CLLocationManager` instance on iOS 9, otherwise the system will stop it after a while.

Swift

```
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
```

Objective C

```
self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true;
```